# Using 3 LAN Connections Simultaneously

Tags: networking, lan

I have ;one onboard lan port and have two additional lan cards totalling to three lan ports. So can i use these simultaneously for internet connection. I know we cannot simultaneously connect to internet using three connections using windows 8. I found a software called connectify and purchased it sometime ago. So using that I can combine the connections. But what I need to know is at a hardware level will the three lan connections create a conflict. That is if i install three lans and connect three separate dsl connection through a modem which then goes into the lan ports. Will all the lan adapters be active a the same time or will one conflict with the other.

Intel i3 Processor
Onboard Lan
2 iball ethernet lan cards in pci slots
windows 8 operating system

Comment: A multi-WAN hardware device may provide a better solution for you... I use devices such as DrayTek Vigor or NetGear that allow multiple WAN connections and you can use them as failover or aggregated for better bandwidth...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your setup how this functions, but you can have several LAN ports active next to each other, and if all 3 have an internet connection with each different IP addresses, and you bridge that into a new connection, this will work.

Do note that if one of the connections has a failing internet connection, it will become harder to diagnose problems, as it will seem that large downloads fail or take considerably longer for no apparent reason.

Lastly, if all 3 internet connections go through the same DSL, it is very likely you cannot establish more than 1 internet connection, or it is capped so in the end the total of 3 connections have the same speed as 1 would have. If they are 3 separate connections, then it will of course go faster, but will also be 3 times expensive, as you pay for 3 dsl connections. A faster connection for one of the dsl lines is usually a lot cheaper than using this solution though.

Comment: Hello I have a follow-up question. First I have 3 separate modems for running the 3 separate connections. It is more cost effective than getting a high speed connection here. So I have one doubt. Can you tell me the procedure to set up to combine these connections from a hardware point of view. What should I purchase and if there is any software other than connectify then suggestions are welcome. Thanks for the help anyways!!!

Comment: Assuming you are on windows 8 and the 3 LAN adapters are installed and working, you can simply use Windows 8 builtin features to create a bridged connection. Go to your `network and internet` in control panel, then `Network and Sharing Center`. On the left, go to `Change adapter settings`. Then Right click one of your LAN adapters, and choose `Bridge Connections`. Then select the other 2 LAN adapters, and it will create a new lan adapter which bridges all 3 LAN adapters.